# How do I find all instances of a plugin using jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I've created a jQuery wee plugin for myself which takes care of showing, hiding and submitting a form to give in-place editing. Currently I have several of these on a page which function independently and I am happy. However, I'm thinking that an 'Edit All' might be useful. I'd therefore want to be able to access all instances of the plugin within the page and access their show/hide/validate/submit functions in unison. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the custom events in jQuery to make this easy.

Something like this:

```
(function($) {      
    $.fn.myPlugin = function() {    
        return this.each(function(){        

            //Plugin Code Goes Here

            $(this).bind("pluginEdit",function(){
                internalEditFunction();
            });         
        });
    };
})(jQuery);
```

Then you can just

```
$(selector).trigger("pluginEdit");
```

Comment: Just came back to this and it perfectly solved another (slightly related) problem I was having. Thanks loads.

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm I guess I could create an array of instances...

```
var plugins = new Array();

plugins.push($('first_editable_section').pluginThing());
plugins.push($('second_editable_section').pluginThing());
```

and access them through that.